# Simple SubSonic 3 Generation issues

Tags: subsonic3

I'm trying to do a proof of concept using SubSonic 3 but Sstraight away i'm hitting numerous errors with the generation. I started making alterations to the generator settings but that seems a little odd when I'm just trying to do a simple one to one mapping of my DB.

Firstly I found an SP that had @delagate as an SP parameter name, this was easily fixed, but should probably be in the standard templates as a user shouldn't have to make template changes for this simple an issue.

Next I found that the system choked on two tables and tried to create signatures the same
the tables where
Field
Fields

now i know SubSonix 2 had a fixPluralClassName property but buggered if I can find one in the template for SubSonic 3

Any help on that one will get me started

Comment: It would help if you indicated what template set you were using.

Comment: Sorry DB is MS SQL 2008 so Sql template generating into c#

Comment: I've also found a few areas where :
if the column is referenced with an "X" suffix then not all refernces to it are correctly suffixed with "X"
IE
ActiveRecord.tt has
   if (tbl.ClassName == col.CleanName)
   {
    col.CleanName += "X";
   }
but lacks the same for the follow usages

public object KeyValue(){
   return this.<#=tbl.PK.CleanName#>;
}
public override int GetHashCode() {
  return this.<#=tbl.PK.CleanName #>;
}
 and several others this comment doesn't have room for

Answer (score 0):

Generally 'X' and 'Datum' type appendages/substitutions happen when you have used a 'reserved' word in a column or table name. In this case 'Reserved' being a word that Subsonic doesn't like to use for data objects.

A couple of rules I follow are;

1. Ensure both table names and column
   names are not 'reserved' words (ie
   'Data' or 'Int' or 'Table')
2. Ensure that each table has a primary key
3. Don't use date and time column types
   as they are not supported yet
   (DateTime is, just not Date and Time types)
4. Don't have a column with the same
   name as the table

The [Subsonic FAQ](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/SubSonic_3_Frequently_Asked_Questions) might be helpful.